# setState value in async button handler function not getting empty in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to set value in asyn buttonHander function. it's working fine in onSortedViewHandler function but when i try to console.log array value in render arrayis empty, i don't know why but it's not rendering

`state = { inputText: "", sortedArrayList: [] };`

```
  onSortedViewHandler = async () => {
    const data = await this.props.sortedContract.methods
      .sortNumberArrayList()
      .call()
      .then((array) => {});

    this.setState({ sortNumberArrayList: data });       // array output is correct here
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.state.sortNumberArrayList);       // array output is correct here
  };
```

it's working fine in this funtion,

but not array show empty in render

```
render() {
console.log(this.state.sortedArrayList);        //but empty here
}
``
```

Comment: the state properties have different names: `sortNumberArrayList` and `sortedArrayList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render() {
 console.log(this.state.sortNumberArrayList);       
}
```

This should render you the correct one. You had different naming state.